# Recycle a vector of characters in negative and positive direction

Tags: r, vector

I have vector of characters, letters and symbols:

```
vec <-c(letters, 0:9, LETTERS, c("!","§","$","%","&"))
```

I would like to build a function `recycle` that can recycle the vector `vec` so that `recycle(vec, 68)` would be similar to `vec[68]` (an `'a'`) and `recycle(vec, -1)` would give an `'&'`.

Answer (score 4):

A vectorized solution:

```
recycle <- function(vec, i) {
  L <- length(vec)
  ind <- (abs(i) - 1) %% L + 1
  res <- ifelse(i > 0, vec[ind], vec[L - ind + 1])
  res[i != 0]
}

> print(recycle(vec, 68))
[1] "a"
> print(recycle(vec, -1))
[1] "&"
> print(recycle(vec, setdiff(-68:68, 0)))
  [1] "&" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t"
 [22] "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
 [43] "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
 [64] "!" "§" "$" "%" "&" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p"
 [85] "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "A"
[106] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V"
[127] "W" "X" "Y" "Z" "!" "§" "$" "%" "&" "a"
> all.equal(recycle(vec, setdiff(-68:68, 0)), recycle(vec, -68:68))
[1] TRUE
> recycle(vec, 0)
character(0)
```

**Edited** to return nothing for an index = `0`.

Comment: Yeap, this is my last sentence. What do you want to return for 0? NA maybe?

Comment: By "vectorized", I mean that the second argument can be a vector of indices, not just only one index.

Comment: Oooh that is superb useful! +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

This could be one simple way:

```
recycle <- function( vec , x ){
  l <- length(vec)   
  #  Deal with negative indices
  if( x < 0 ){
    vec <- rev(vec)
    x <- abs(x)
  }
  #  Extend vector if required index is longer
  if( x > l ){
    t <- x %/% l + 1
    vec <- rep( vec , t )
  }
  # Get value
  vec[x]
}
```

Which gives:

```
recycle (vec,68)
#[1] "a"

recycle(vec,-1)
#[1] "&"

recycle(vec,0)
#character(0)
```

Comment: In the `x > l` case, I think you can directly use the length.out argument to `rep`.

Comment: @lmo not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about the question, but something like `rep(1:2, length.out=5)`. So then you could say `if(x > l) vec <- rep(vec, length.out=x)`.

Comment: @lmo ah yes I see what you mean. Yes I think that works too and would be quicker and more efficient. I will edit this answer unless you want to provide your own?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%%`:

```
recycle0 <- function(vec,x) vec[[((x-1) %% length(vec))+1]]

recycle0(vec,1)  # [1] "a"
recycle0(vec,68) # [1] "a"
recycle0(vec,67) # [1] "&"
```

it works with null or negative numbers too but then it's offset by one compare to what you ask:

```
recycle0(vec,0)   # [1] "&"
recycle0(vec,-1)  # [1] "%"
```

so let's adapt it and deal with the `0` value:

```
recycle <- function(vec,x) if(!x) NA else vec[[((x - sign(x)/2 -0.5) %% length(vec))+1]]

recycle(vec,1)  # [1] "a"
recycle(vec,68) # [1] "a"
recycle(vec,67) # [1] "&"
recycle(vec,-1) # [1] "&"
recycle(vec,0)  # [1] "NA"
```